# Magento database upgrade 1.4.2 to 1.9 verification

Tags: php, mysql, magento, upgrade

I have just attempted to upgrade Magento from 1.4.2 to 1.9. I did all the prep work according to the docs. When it came to the point of connecting a copy of the existing database to to the new 1.9 files then visiting the base url so that Magento could upgrade the database it took about 5-10 seconds to load then just showed the site as normal. So my question is, was I supposed to see a screen telling me the database was being upgraded?

According to the docs the process could take hours which it obviously didn't. The store only has 1200 orders and 1100 products could the process have been that quick. How can I verify if the database was upgraded?

Comment: _" the process **could** take hours "_ could is the keyword, another way to say it is _"the process **MIGHT** take hours"_ It might take hours, it could take 5 seconds.

Comment: Indeed Magento is just preventing it-self. Not to actual mock you, but in the eyes Magento, a 1200 orders and 1100 products webstore is a really tiny one. sSo that makes sense.

Comment: The only way you know if a Magento database upgrade is successful is when you've run the new version for a couple days without it throwing a stacktrace complaining about a foreign key issue, a missing table, column mismatch or other SQL error. This is despite the record updates in `core_resource` With 10000 product records, 1.4.2 to 1.5.1.0 was long, 1.5.1.0 to 1.6.2.0 was longer and 1.6.2.0 to 1.9.2.2, well, it happened so quick, I thought disaster had struck, it was the first time it went through without failure on the first three tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updating process on Magento is indeed transparent to the user, the goal is actually to be able to launch new functionalities or upgrade module without the customer / visitor even noticing this.

What you can actually look at to see if you database is up to date is to find in the folders **app/code/core/Mage/*/*/sql/** the file upgrading to the highest version.

Example of a files there :

- `upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php` => highest version = the last part of the file after the dash => **1.6.0.6**
- `install-16.0.0.php` =>highest version after the dash, again => **16.0.0**

Once you have the highest version, open the table *core_resource* of your database and see, for the same module, if the version stated there is equal to the highest you find in the file names.

Real life example :

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.18-1.6.0.0.19.php` is the file I identified as being the highest version for the module catalog.

My database should then stand **catalog_setup** => **1.6.0.0.19**

And indeed :

```
select * from core_resource where code like 'catalog_setup' 
#catalog_setup is actually the name of the folder under the folder sql... well not really if you want to know more about magento it really is a XML node name, but as a standard it should be the same as the folder name

code            | version       | data_version
catalog_setup   | 1.6.0.0.19    | 1.6.0.0.19
```